# Inconsistent output with jQuery and Lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, jquery, lightning-apps

With jQuery I'm able to select elements on the page on my lightning app. When I execute this command in the console

```
$('#all-items table tbody tr');
```

I get

[image]

When I assign this command to a variable in a script in a Static resource, like so

```
var $imgs = $('#all-items table tbody tr');          // Get the whiteboard
console.log($imgs);
```

the console returns

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are running inside Locker.

If that's the case, for your example, jQuery will return a collection of SecureElements, and the browser console uses the generic view (JS style) for those objects instead of outputting an HTML version.